# INotifyChanged Interface is not working as expected C# Wpf (first time I'm implementing it)

Tags: c#, wpf, interface, datagrid, inotify

I'm working on a WPF application which contains a DataGrid with person details like first name, last name, email and so on.

I'm using `ObservableCollection` list as `DataSource` to my `DataGrid`:

```
public ObservableCollection<Persons> personsLists = new ObservableCollection<Person>(Controller.SelectAllPersons());
```

What I would like to achieve is next:

When I change First Name or Last Name for example,
I'm saving it to database and I would like to update DataGrid immediately. I tried implementing INotifyPropertyChanged by following [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229614(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
public class Person : MyInherit, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    #region Attributes
    private string _fullName;
    private int _townId;
    private string _firstName;
    private Town _town;
    private string _lastName;
    #endregion

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    #region Properties

    public Town Town
    {
        get { return _town; }
        set
        {
            _town = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Town");
        }
    }
    public int TownId
    {
        get { return _townId; }
        set
        {
            _townId = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("TownId");
        }
    }

    public string FullName
    {
        get { return _fullName; }
        set
        {
            _fullName = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("FullName");
        }
    }

    public string FirstName
    {
        get { return _firstName; }
        set
        {
            _firstName = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("FirstName");
        }
    }

    public string LastName
    {
        get { return _lastName; }
        set
        {
            _lastName = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("LastName");
        }
    }
}
```

And this is where I am editing my person object on my UI form:

```
private void btnPersonEdit_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Person selectedPerson = (Person)(dtgPersons.SelectedItem);

    if (selectedPerson != null)
    {
        //GetExistingPerson from DataGrid (gettin obj from list which is source to a DataGrid so it's same as getting it from DataGrid)
        var person = personsLists.Where(d => d.Id == selectedPerson.Id).FirstOrDefault();

        if (person != null)
        {
            person.FirstName = txtFirstName.Text;
            person.LastName = txtLastName.Text;

            person.Town = (Town)cmbTowns.SelectedItem;
            person.TownId = selectedPerson.Town.Id;

            //Apply changes to a database
            Person lastUpdated = Controller.UpdatePerson(person);

            dtgPersons.UnselectAll();
        }
    }

    //After this I thought the same item I edited should be updated immediately on a DataGrid but obviously I did something wrong
}
```

How could I keep my DataGrid updated with this INotifyPropertyChanged Interface without setting source one more time, 
because I think it is bad for performance to do something like this:

```
dtg.ItemsSource=null;
dtg.ItemsSource=  personsLists;
```

XAML:

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row="1" IsReadOnly="True" Name="dtgPersons" EnableColumnVirtualization = "True"
            EnableRowVirtualization ="True" SelectionUnit="FullRow" Background="White" Margin="0,5,0,0" 
            AutoGenerateColumns="False" RowHeaderWidth="0" MaxWidth="4000" MaxHeight="2000" HorizontalGridLinesBrush="#0091EA" 
            VerticalGridLinesBrush="#0091EA" CanUserAddRows="False" FontSize="{x:Static local:Globals.dataGridfontSizeContent}" 
            RowHeight="30" SelectionChanged="dtgPersons_SelectionChanged" >
    <DataGrid.CellStyle>
        <StaticResource ResourceKey="DataGridCentering"/>
    </DataGrid.CellStyle>
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#0091EA"/>
            <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="1"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{x:Static local:Globals.dataGridfontSizeHeader}"/>
            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Arial"/>
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="40"/>
        </Style>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="LightBlue"/>
    </DataGrid.Resources>   
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding FirstName}"   CellStyle="{StaticResource DataGridCenteringLeft}"  
            Header="First Name"   Foreground="Black" FontSize="16" FontFamily="Verdana" Width="*"  />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding LastName}"   CellStyle="{StaticResource DataGridCenteringLeft}"    
            Header="Last Name"   Foreground="Black" FontSize="16" FontFamily="Verdana" Width="*"  />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: Set the properties of an instance of `Person` *that's actually in the grid*. I already told you that. Don't just create a new one, set its properties, and then throw it away. There's no magic here. It just does what you tell it to. Change the actual object you want to change, not a different one.

Comment: In the code you posted, I don't see any evidence that the `Person` object you are modifying is in any way related to the collection bound to your `DataGrid`, never mind a member of it. But it's impossible to know for sure, because you haven't provided a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces your problem. Please improve your question.

Comment: Are you trying to edit a Person object that is displayed in the DataGrid or what is your issue?

Comment: @mm8 yes I am trying to edit a person object that is displayed in my DataGrid, and after I edit it I'm saving changes to a DB but I would like to refresh DataGrid without setting source one more time..

Comment: @EdPlunkett I think I did it as you said before, but I didn't paste correct block of code, sorry mate, check for my Edit, is that a correct way to set properties of an instance of Person that's acctually in the grid.

Comment: @Roxy'Pro Thanks, that's making a lot more sense now. What's this business with `personsLists`? Isn't `dtgPersons.SelectedItem` the actual object in the `DataGrid`?

Comment: Are you sure `person` isn't null where you check `if (person != null)` in `btnPersonEdit_Click`?

Comment: @EdPlunkett Yes I am, because on DataGrid event selection changed I am filling TextBoxes and by editing content inside of them I'm in fact editing values of my object Properties (values of selected datagrid item)..

Comment: I have no idea what that sentence means. If you put a breakpoint on `person.FirstName = txtIme.Text;`, do you break into the debugger on that line of code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139802/discussion-between-roxypro-and-ed-plunkett).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you looking for a `Person` object in the `listaselectedPerson` collection? I guess you want to set the properties of the selected one:

```
private void btnPersonEdit_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Person selectedPerson = (Person)(dtgPersons.SelectedItem);
    if (selectedPerson != null)
    {
        selectedPerson.FirstName = txtIme.Text;
        selectedPerson.LastName = txtPrezime.Text;
        selectedPerson.Town = (Town)cmbTowns.SelectedItem;
        selectedPerson.TownId = selectedPerson.Town.Id;

        //Apply changes to a database
        Person lastUpdated = Controller.UpdatePerson(selectedPerson);
        dtgPersons.UnselectAll();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes I want to set properties of selected one, and that's goin on way you did it there, but somehow DataGrid which is containing informations about Persons is not refreshing/updating or whatever, I need to close window and reopen it to see changes in my DataGrid, My window is separated in two big columns, to the left is few textboxes which are being filled from selected DataGrid item which is (DataGrid) on the right, and when I edit some persons and click save, I can't see any changes in my DataGrid where I ussually see lists of currently active Persons in my DB.

Comment: Are you saying that the "dtgPersons" DataGrid is not updated?

Comment: Yes it is not updated unless I reopeon Window, or if I set ItemsSource manually like dtg.ItemsSource=null; dtg.ItemsSource=collection; Collection itself is updated there are new values for properties but If you take a look on DataGrid in column "First Name" for example, there will be still old name before any changes, until  I refresh a grid on way I mentioned (setting DataGrid source manually)..

Comment: What d you think mate why that DataGrid column wont update itself when I change propery of selected item from datagrid?

Comment: What if you only set the FirstName property to some static value like "test"? Remove the rest of the code including the call to the UpdatePerson.

Comment: No need or our worries anymore my dear friend it works now, I think I gone crazy, btw I implemented INotifyChanged interface as it should be implemented?

Comment: you'r awesome :D